# Calculation error in java code (leet code)

Tags: java, logic

QUESTION:-
'Hercy wants to save money for his first car. He puts money in the Leetcode bank every day.

He starts by putting in $1 on Monday, the first day. Every day from Tuesday to Sunday, he will put in $1 more than the day before. On every subsequent Monday, he will put in $1 more than the previous Monday.
Given n, return the total amount of money he will have in the Leetcode bank at the end of the nth day.'

CODE :-

```
public class Practice {
    public static int weekCalc (int a , int n){
        // a - week count 
        //n - number of days 
        int c = (n/2)*(2*a + n - 1);
        return c;
    }

    public static int total (int n ){
        int sum = 0;
        if (n<=7){
            sum +=  weekCalc(1, n); 
        } else {
            int num = n/7;
            for (int i =1 ; i<= num; i++){
                sum +=  weekCalc(i, 7);
            }
            int d = n%7;
            sum += weekCalc(num +1, d);
        }
        return sum ;

    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
       int ans = total(5);
       System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

This is the Leetcode 1716. Leetcode bank problem . I tried solving it using sum of AP but there seems to be an error in the weekCalc function , it isn't giving me the correct output .
Like for weekCalc (1,5) the output should be 15 but its giving me 12 . I have cross checked the code several times ; I know there are other methods to solve this question but why isn't this one working ??

Comment: I would suggest checking `n/2` thats probably wrong, since you are doing Integer math. I haven't bothered checking the rest of the logic.

Comment: too complicated (and mixed up¹.) *Brute force*, that is, just do two nested loops: inner one for days in a week; outer one for total days - can also be done if one loop, and using `% 7` to do different logic for Monday (**¹** code seems like doing a mix of math solution and loop solution)

Comment: (a simpler solution, basically loop all days and do `total += (day/7+1) + (day%7)` )

Comment: The problem with this approach is ignoring intermediate results. Such tasks help to understand how quickly you can entangle, although there are no hundreds or thousands lines. Structure your intermediate data. Create collections of weeks which contain daily income, a kind of accounting conduit. When the data is arranged this way, the final balance will be easy to calculate. Same as weekly. Then, having all the data visually, you can easily see where it does not look like expected. This will help you in programming much more than trying to catch this imperative algorithm by the tail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way to do this:

```
    int totalMoney(int n) {
        int current_days=0;
        int total=0;
        int monday_deposit=0;
        int prev_deposit=0;

        while(current_days!=n){
            if(current_days%7==0){ // It is a Monday!!!
                monday_deposit+=1;
                prev_deposit=monday_deposit;
            } else{
                prev_deposit+=1;
            }
            total+=prev_deposit;
            current_days++;
        }

        return total;
    }
```

The core idea is to maintain the prev deposit on the basis of the days. I hope the code is self explanatory.